# Binary cross-compatibility between Jessie and Stretch

Tags: raspbian-jessie, c++, compatibility, raspbian-stretch, software-compatibility

Will binaries compiled on Jessie work on Stretch?  What about the reverse?

The program in question is written in C++ (thus depends on the C++ standard library), but has no other external dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

> Will binaries compiled on Jessie work on Stretch?

They should, yes.  Glibc has a pretty high degree of [backward ABI (application binary interface) compatibility](https://abi-laboratory.pro/tracker/timeline/glibc/).

Other libraries may not have that, but if there is any trouble you can always install an older version alongside the new one -- possibly ripping it precompiled from a jessie package.

> What about the reverse?  The program in question is written in C++...

This may have more to do with how much new fangled C++ you use in relation to features implemented in the compiler.  I think most if not all of C++ 11 was in the last jessie compiler, and implementation of C++ 14/17 continues.  But you will be very aware of this if it applies.

However, beware that forward ABI compatibility is generally *not* a goal with any library, so this could be an issue anyway.

Comment: I have a small scientific software package (actually it's for Mathematica), and I also provide RPi binaries (so people don't have to compile it themselves, which is painful to setup and takes 1+ hr).  I am simply trying to decide when to upgrade to Stretch. I am perfectly happy with Jessie for now and the only concern is to maximize the compatibility of my package.  It sounds like it's better if I stay on Jessie for a few more months.

Comment: You really should provide two packages.  Pretty sure all of the distro packages get recompiled even when there is no version change.

Comment: Of course that's what one would do in an ideal world, but I definitely cannot provide two packages.  I do not have the time and resources, and the Raspberry Pi is already the lowest priority target. I can barely keep up with x86_64 Linux/OSX/Windows versions.  It has to be either Jessie or Stretch, but not both.

Comment: I should really take that back.  To be fair most third party binary packages for linux are distributed just targeting hardware (e.g. x86_64) or at best come in generic .rpm and/or .deb files without any specific distro version.  You just state your prereq (upstream) versions.  I think it is mostly just the distros themselves that provide per version things.